# Sci-fi book where a 3D man travels into 4D world and meets some creatures there

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a sci-fi book where the protagonist (a man) travels into a 4D world with the help of 4D creature.

Details I remember:

- Creature covered his sides with some membrane in order to prevent his inners to fall off to 4d.
- Once he returned into 3D flipped, so his left/right changed.
- There were some damages in our 3D-membrane-world so some kind of a void appeared.
- Happy ending.

I read it in English, somewhere around 2020, so it was published earlier. It's not too old and not too new. Please help me identify it.

The 4D creature got him to visit another creature. I don't remember whether it was its parent or king.

Comment: I read about a story that was kind of a sequel to Flatland, where the MC then went to flatland to apologize for not understanding the square properly, but I'm not sure if it wasn't just an imaginary story mentioned in another story I actually read...

Comment: Of course, the happy ending would be brief, as a flipped human wouldn't be able to digest food anymore =D.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_life

Comment: @Cireo Something similar was addressed in the A.C Clarke story [Technical Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Error) (from 1950).  And amusingly, my link references your link!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found it.

**Spaceland, 2003, by Rudy Rucker**

Spaceland is a science fiction novel by American mathematician and computer scientist Rudy Rucker, and published in 2002 by Tor Books.

In a tribute to Edwin Abbott's Flatland, a classic mathematical fantasy about a 2-dimensional being (A. Square) who receives a surprise visit from a higher-dimensional sphere, Rudy Rucker's Spaceland describes the life of Joe Cube, an average, modern-day Silicon Valley hotshot who one day discovers the fourth dimension from an unexpected visitation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceland_(novel))

Comment: Thanks for coming back and letting us know, and welcome to SF&F!  Please come back in 2 days and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 8):

You *might* be remembering [*Death's End*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death%27s_End) by Cixin Liu (the concluding book of the [*Remembrance of Earth's Past*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_of_Earth%27s_Past) trilogy). In it:

- A few characters encounter 4D space in different situations.
- While not covered with a special membrane (aside from skin), 3D humans encountering 4D space needed to take care not to spill their bodies into a fourth dimensional direction.
- A space-faring human encounters a 4D entity (maybe even 5D or higher?), and converses with it: a kind of intelligent monument serving as a knowledge repository, warning sign, and cenotaph for an entire civilization. The entity proves helpful.
- Lower dimensional space is a kind of weapon used in conflict by beings of a higher dimension. The Earth and humanity's familiar 3D universe was the result of collapsing some of a 4D space into 3 dimensions in order to destroy a 4D civilization. Later in the book a 2D weapon destroys parts of 3D space in a spectacular fashion.
- *Death's End* arguably has a happy ending, in that

> the destruction of humanity feared at the start of the trilogy did not really play out as imagined. Perhaps some remnant of humanity even survived the end of the universe.

Comment: I know this book and I read full trilogy. That is not what I'm looking for. Interesting that I can't remember anything about "membrane to prevent spilling into 4D".

Comment: @AlexanderC I seem to recall it was when the folks on the *Gravity* or *Blue Space* ships first encountered the 4D zone. I think one of their crew may have been injured and they were trying to investigate? Now I need to go reread. :)

Answer (score 6):

This sounds very similar to [The Boy Who Reversed Himself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Reversed_Himself) by William Sleator.  It has:

- 3D individuals who travel into 4D
- People and objects can come back reversed
- Creatures that the main characters interact with in 4D
- YA novel with a reasonably happy ending

I wouldn't be surprised if the other books mentioned here took some inspiration from this book.